API Connectivity using "PKCS12" certificate file

I am getting below Error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.StringEntity;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class CurlToJava {
    private static final String P12_FILE_PATH = "path/to/your/pfa-data-service.p12";
    private static final String P12_PASSWORD = "PassPhrase";
    private static final String TARGET_URL
            = "http://B17121-"+
            "vip.nam.nsroot:100/monitoringDaily/api/download" +
            "/cs/cars/system%20Views/Obliger%20fund%20Details" +
            "(as69734_202405080737)?soeId=system&delimiter=%7C"
            + "&addHeadandTail=true&filename=testDownload";
    private static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "0cb93babee5f6370007632b93365109a8";

    private static SSLContext createSSLContext() throws Exception {
        // Load the PKCS12 KeyStore
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        try (FileInputStream keyStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream(P12_FILE_PATH)) {
            keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, P12_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        }

        return SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, P12_PASSWORD.toCharArray())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = createSSLContext();
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setConnectionManager(
                            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                                    .build()
                    )
                    .build();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TARGET_URL);

            // Set your headers
            httpPost.setHeader("accept", "*/*");
            httpPost.setHeader("AUTH_TOKEN", AUTH_TOKEN);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Execute HTTP POST request
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                 InputStream responseStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                 OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("testDownload.csv")) {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = responseStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                System.out.println("Response Code: " + response.getCode());
                System.out.println("Response downloaded to testDownload.csv");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


with Above code I am getting Error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

You probably need to import the certificate

Does this answer your question? Java: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
